# Is it possible to nest YAML anchors hierarchically?

Tags: yaml

I'm new to working with YAML. I'd like to know if it is possible to 'nest' YAML anchors as I have attempted in the example below. Unfortunately, I get an error `YAMLException: unidentified alias "foo" at line 13, column 19: category: *foo ^`

```
namespace: &namespace-definition
  name: "Hellow world"
  value: "hw"
categories: &categories
  - &foo:
    name: "foo"
    namespace: *namespace-definition
  - &bar:
    name: "bar"
    namespace: *namespace-definition
keys:
  - name: "element1"
    category: *foo
  - name: "element2"
    category: *bar
```

Is there another way to achieve what I am trying to do, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anchors in your example are named `foo:` and `bar:`, not `foo` and `bar`.

Remove the colon after them and it will work:

```
namespace: &namespace-definition
  name: "Hellow world"
  value: "hw"
categories: &categories
  - &foo
    name: "foo"
    namespace: *namespace-definition
  - &bar
    name: "bar"
    namespace: *namespace-definition
keys:
  - name: "element1"
    category: *foo
  - name: "element2"
    category: *bar
```